# Possible un handled promise rejection: Type error: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.toastInstance_root.showToast')

Tags: react-native, logout

Am trying to add log out functionality using API call ,

```
  logOut = () => {
this.props.dispatch(logOut()).then(
  (response) => {
    Toast.show({
      text: response,
      position: 'bottom',
      type: 'success'
    });
  });
this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
};
```

in both success and error block i am clearing the local state , but i cannot able to show the toast message in the submit function it is throwing above warning instead of toast message.what mistake i made here

```
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  dispatch(startAuth());
  http
    .get('/api/auth/logout')
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch(authSuccess(null));
      resolve(response.message);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      dispatch(authSuccess(null));
      reject();
    });
});
```

Comment: make sure `response` is what you expect when you're passing it to the Toast

Comment: i am getting the response , and it is showing toast when i hide the navigation to home page

Comment: Did you try `await`? Call function with await `await this.props.dispatch(logOut())`. And make sure that your logout function is asynchronous. Like `async logOut() { ... }`.